# Reading Json slash in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm reading a JSON file through javascript. I'm having trouble getting **today/_text** because of the forward slash. I can get **today** successfully by doing: `{{hours.results[0].today}}`. How would I get `today/_text`? I've tried:

`today\/_text`

`today/\_text`

`today//_text`

`today\\/_text`

```
 {"offset":0,"results":[{"today/_text":"Today:YES","today/_source":"/hours/1","today":"2,3,4"}]}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets

Answer (score 2):

`hours.results[0]["today/_text"]` should do the trick!

`hours.results[0]` returns an object that has that as a key, making that the easiest way to access the property in question.